# What should I have in mind when preparing files for print in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, tiff

The title makes it pretty clear but maybe I'm not the only one who's curious and wonders about things.

I'm currently designing a brochure in InDesign. I've made the background layout in Photoshop and saved it as `.tiff`, then imported it in to InDesign.

Text, shapes and photos were introduced via InDesign. (Should I create curves out of text?)

My InDesign layout has 5 mm bleed on each side.

How do I deliver the file to the print shop?

What should I have in mind when preparing files for print in InDesign?

Answer (score 3):

**Export as PDF/X-1a with bleeds and marks.**

If all your linked images are the correct resolution, that's all there is to it. Provide the printer with the PDF/X file.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience you should ask the print shop what they need. I usually deliver as a pdfx-1a:2001, compatible with acrobat 4. That is what the print shop told me they needed.

Also, be sure to match color settings.

Answer (score -1):

This one problem always screws me over. When you send your file to print you have to split your document into single spreads as opposed to double. By splitting your document the page numbers get messed up :( So make sure you set up another master page that would work appropriately with the page split.

Comment: That only is a problem if you designed your document the wrong way around to begin with. The OP does not seem to have this problem.